# Multiplying by Loewner-ordered matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are symmetric positive (semi-)definite, and $A<B$ in Loewner order, meaning $B-A$ is positive (semi-)definite. Is it true that, for a symmetric positive-definite $C$, we have $ACA < BCB$?

If it helps, $A$ and $B$ can be assumed to be invertible.

Comment: Are you trying to show that $\forall A,B\exists C$ or $\forall A,B\forall C$? $\forall A,B\forall C$ can be easily disproven using computer calculations by testing random positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: The function $X\mapsto X^2$ is not *operator monotone* (search for these keywords perhaps for more information), so this fails even when $C=1$.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's an excellent counterexample.